# Enums, Singletons and Deserialization

Tags: java, enums, singleton, deserialization

Enums are considered best way for singletons and one of reasons for this is that it implicitly inherits `Serializable`.

But how enums prevents de-serialization problem of singletons?

Comment: Enum is a singleton but what are the problems of deserialization of singletons ?

Comment: @clinton: if you make a singleton serializable, and don't care about how it's deserialized, you and up with a new instance of your singleton each time it's deserialized, which breaks its singletonness.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the info. I had not looked up that issue regarding singletons before now. Or it may not have struck me as important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The serialization mechanism handles them in a [special, specific way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#enum). But traditional singletons can be deserialized fine by defining a `readResolve()` method that returns the unique instance. See http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization as an argument for using enum for singleton is nonsense.

If the enum singleton is stateful, the state is lost during serialization/deserialization.

If the singleton is stateless, who cares about its identity?

Comment: If the singleton is stateless, and the code uses (for example) `if (someVar == SomeSingleton.INSTANCE)`, you really care about its identity.

Comment: There's no real world use case. Jushua Bloc made this thing up. Usually a singleton should NOT be serializable anyway, using enum to facilitate serialization is just wrong. Also, singleton is an implementation strategy, not something we should publicize at interface.